# Gradle: Why Exec-derived tasks does not see custom project properties?

Tags: groovy, gradle

Say, we have following property set in build.gradle:

```
ext.PING = "PONG"
```

Now we create to tasks:

```groovy
 task ping(type: Exec) {
     commandLine 'echo', project.hasProperty('PING')
 }

 task pong() {
        doLast {
            println project.hasProperty('PING')
        }   
    }
```

If will run `gradle pong` we'll see `true` printed, if we'll run `gradle ping` we won't.

The question is: How can we resolve such propeties at the moment we are forming commandLine command? The thing is that in `doLast` or `doFirst` we'll see evaluated properties but this does not help - commandLine should be formed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Since the forming of command line arguments happens during the configuration phase, you have to check, whether your `ext.PING = "PONG"` goes before the `ping` task. For example, I've tested it with simple build script like:

```
ext.PING = "PONG"
task ping(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'echo', project.hasProperty('PING')
}
```

The result of echo is true, but for:

```
task ping(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'echo', project.hasProperty('PING')
}
ext.PING = "PONG"
```

Result is false.

You have to check, have you set this property before the ping task configuration. As for `doFirst` and `doLast`, they are executed during execution phase, that means, that all configurations are done and property exists.